# unknown column in 'field list' with existing data

Tags: mysql, sql

```
| enrollment | CREATE TABLE `enrollment` (
  `SSN` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `CourseNumber` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `Quarter` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Grade` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SSN`,`CourseNumber`,`Quarter`),
  KEY `CourseNumber` (`CourseNumber`),
  KEY `Quarter` (`Quarter`),
  CONSTRAINT `enrollment_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`SSN`) REFERENCES `Student` (`SSN`),
  CONSTRAINT `enrollment_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`CourseNumber`) REFERENCES `Course` (`CourseNumber`),
  CONSTRAINT `enrollment_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`Quarter`) REFERENCES `section` (`Quarter`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |


| student | CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `SSN` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Major` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SSN`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |

mysql> select * from student;
+-----------+----------------+-----------+
| SSN       | Name           | Major     |
+-----------+----------------+-----------+
| 111111111 | Danny James    | History   |
| 123123123 | John White     | Chemistry |


mysql> INSERT INTO ENROLLMENT (SSN, CourseNumber, Quarter, Grade) 
values (‘111111111’, '220','Winter2014', 'A');
```

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column '‘111111111’' in 'field list'

I am a beginner in SQL.
I clearly have a student who has '111111111' as their SSN. But it still says it's unknown column. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is here:

> ```
>  mysql> INSERT INTO ENROLLMENT (SSN, CourseNumber, Quarter, Grade) 
>  values (‘111111111’, '220','Winter2014', 'A');
>         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

You have used curly quotes `‘` `’` rather than standard single quotes `'` to define the first value.

To fix:

```
  mysql> INSERT INTO ENROLLMENT (SSN, CourseNumber, Quarter, Grade) 
  values ('111111111', '220','Winter2014', 'A');
```